# Loosing authentication on file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, forms-authentication

When I upload file (ex. photo), I'm loosing user session, web-site redirects me to the login page.
I'm uploading files in a different folder, not in project's folder.

Web.config, system.web:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms defaultUrl="/" loginUrl="/Account/Login" name="_User" timeout="60" path="/" />
    </authentication>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.7" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="52428" />
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" responseHeaderEncoding="utf-8" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="/" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect" />
</system.web>
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is an example of a complete URL that is working? What is the complete login URL? What is the URL to the upload route? How big is the file being uploaded (and have you tried a very small image - less than 1KB)?

Comment: It is working sometimes on the same photo (looses session or not). I do not have full URL, I'm using path of it (/Admin/EditPhoto/). Login path: /Account/Login/ . File I've uploading is not more than 5mb.

Comment: What does `timeout="60"` mean?

Comment: After 60 min, user session will be expired and user will be logged out.

Comment: Is it possible that is causing your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always set the domain in the **cookies**, and **form**, and preferable with out the `www.` so the cookies can work even if the user or the url did not include it.

`<httpCookies domain="domain.com"  />`

`<forms domain="domain.com" />`

This is one of the possible issue - Other can be the `requireSSL` field.